# Set cookie not over HTTPS in ASP.NET 5

Tags: asp.net-core, cookies, identityserver4, samesite, asp.net5

I have two microservices. One is for identity. I am trying to set auth cookie and I have this middleware:

```
app.UseCookiePolicy(new CookiePolicyOptions
{
    MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None,
    Secure = CookieSecurePolicy.None,
    HttpOnly = Microsoft.AspNetCore.CookiePolicy.HttpOnlyPolicy.None
});
```

And also this service:

```
services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddCookie(options =>
    {
        options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
        options.Cookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.None;
        options.Cookie.SecurePolicy = CookieSecurePolicy.None;
        options.Cookie.IsEssential = true;
    });
```

And also browser throws this warning:

[image]

So I want to know if it is possible or not to set cookie not over HTTPS ???

Comment: Because you are not setting your cookie as secure. Secure property should be true. Read more here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/samesite?view=aspnetcore-6.0

Comment: @RajeshG ok, but after, it will say that I have set secure attribute, but I do not set cookie from HTTPS, won't it ??

Comment: I was thinking you need cookie over https. Please read the about samesite attribute below. As per documentation, samesite none will work only with secure cookie.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie/SameSite

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set the cookie over Https, otherwise it will not work.

This is because the **Samesite** cookie functionality requires that it is done over HTTPs when the cookies reaches the browser.

see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie/SameSite

That says:

> Cookies with SameSite=None must now also specify the Secure attribute
> (they require a secure context/HTTPS).

To complement this answer, I wrote a blog post that goes into more detail about this topic: [Debugging cookie problems](https://nestenius.se/2023/10/09/debugging-cookie-problems/)

Comment: Ok, thanks, I will read it.